# how to define two instances of StreamsBuilderFactoryBean

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am new for Spring Kafka. For some reason, I want to create two StreamsBuilderFactoryBean, as you can see I defined two StreamsBuilderFactoryBean one named "`commonDSLBuilder`" and the other is "`propertyDSLBuilder`" with `props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 4)`. So "`commonDSLBuilde`" create only one consumer but "`propertyDSLBuilder`" create four consumers.

```
 @Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaStreamsConfig {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaStreamsConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.kafka.stream.application-id}")
    private String applicationId;

    @Bean(name = "commonDSLBuilder")
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean commonDSLBuilder() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        StreamsConfig streamsConfig = new StreamsConfig(props);
        StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(streamsConfig);
        streamsBuilder.setSingleton(Boolean.FALSE);
        return streamsBuilder;
    }

    @Bean(name = "propertyDSLBuilder")
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean propertyDSLBuilder() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 4);
        StreamsConfig streamsConfig = new StreamsConfig(props);
        CleanupConfig cleanupConfig = new CleanupConfig(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE);
        StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(streamsConfig, cleanupConfig);
        streamsBuilder.setSingleton(Boolean.FALSE);
        return streamsBuilder;
    }
}
```

and I use "`commonDSLBuilder`" like this

```
@Configuration
public class BindPostDSL {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BindPostDSL.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("commonDSLBuilder")
    private StreamsBuilder builder;

    @Bean(name = "bindPostKStream")
    public KStream<String, String> kStream() {
        log.info("bind 事件处理启动");
            KStream<String, String> stream = builder.stream("test");
            stream.foreach((key, value) -> {
                log.info("receive kafka bind post,key:{},value:{}", key, value);
            });
            return stream;
    }
}
```

But when I start the application 5 consumers(1 from `commonDSLBuilder` + 4 from `propertyDSLBuilder` I guess) will be created, how can I fix this.

```
2018-08-06 10:34:12 [test-streams-827fcc9b-3b9a-46f3-a941-961033cdb2cf-StreamThread-1] INFO  StreamThread:336 - stream-thread [test-streams-827fcc9b-3b9a-46f3-a941-961033cdb2cf-StreamThread-1] Starting
2018-08-06 10:34:13 [test-streams-579948de-2e4a-4af4-acbe-542304a95167-StreamThread-2] INFO  StreamThread:336 - stream-thread [test-streams-579948de-2e4a-4af4-acbe-542304a95167-StreamThread-2] Starting
2018-08-06 10:34:13 [test-streams-579948de-2e4a-4af4-acbe-542304a95167-StreamThread-4] INFO  StreamThread:336 - stream-thread [test-streams-579948de-2e4a-4af4-acbe-542304a95167-StreamThread-4] Starting
2018-08-06 10:34:13 [test-streams-579948de-2e4a-4af4-acbe-542304a95167-StreamThread-3] INFO  StreamThread:336 - stream-thread [test-streams-579948de-2e4a-4af4-acbe-542304a95167-StreamThread-3] Starting
2018-08-06 10:34:13 [test-streams-579948de-2e4a-4af4-acbe-542304a95167-StreamThread-5] INFO  StreamThread:336 - stream-thread [test-streams-579948de-2e4a-4af4-acbe-542304a95167-StreamThread-5] Starting
```

Comment: you have `streamsBuilder.setSingleton(Boolean.FALSE);`. I think you don't need that, you need to use the same StreamsBuilderFactoryBean for specific consumer.
`NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG` specifies the number of threads to execute stream processing (parallelism). what exactly is wrong with your code?

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi I want to create to tow `KSteam` instances. one named `bindKStream` which only use one thread to execute. the other one named `perperyKStream` which use four threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are in the right direction.
you need to have two beans `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` and two beans `KStream`. each KStream will have specific StreamsBuilderFactoryBean. you don't need to invoke `setSingleton(Boolean.FALSE);` on streamsBuilder.

```
@Bean
public FactoryBean<StreamsBuilder> commonDSLBuilder() {
    ...
    StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(streamsConfig);
    return streamsBuilder;
}

@Bean
public FactoryBean<StreamsBuilder> propertyDSLBuilder() {
    ...
    StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(streamsConfig, cleanupConfig);
    return streamsBuilder;
}

@Bean
public KStream<String, String> bindKStream(StreamsBuilder commonDSLBuilder) {
    KStream<String, String> kStream = commonDSLBuilder.stream("commonTopicName");
    kStream.foreach((key, value) -> { ...  });
    return kStream;
}

@Bean
public KStream<String, String> perperyKStream(StreamsBuilder propertyDSLBuilder) {
    KStream<String, String> kStream = propertyDSLBuilder.stream("propertyTopicName");
    kStream.foreach((key, value) -> { ... });
    return kStream;
}
```